# Regular expression for dropdown list

Tags: java, regex, jmeter, load-testing

THIS IS MY HTML CODE.

```
  <select name="account.languagePreference"><option value="english">english</option>
<option value="japanese">japanese</option></select>

<select name="account.favouriteCategoryId"><option value="FISH">FISH</option>
<option value="DOGS">DOGS</option>
<option value="REPTILES">REPTILES</option>
<option value="CATS">CATS</option>
<option value="BIRDS">BIRDS</option></select>
```

Question :- i want Regular expression for second dropdown list (answer should be like this as mention below)

```
 Match[][]=FISH
 Match[][]=DOGS
 Match[][]=REPTILES
 Match[][]=CATS
 Match[][]=BIRDS
```

please help me i am not able to extract complete matching.

i have used regex as

```
<select name="account.favouriteCategoryId">.+|\s+<option value="(.*?)">.*?</option>.+|\s+</select>
```

and getting o/p as

```
Match count: 6
Match[1][0]= 
<option value="japanese">japanese</option></select></td>
Match[1][1]=japanese
  Match[2][0]=<select name="account.favouriteCategoryId"><option value="FISH">FISH</option>
Match[2][1]=null
Match[3][0]=
<option value="DOGS">DOGS</option>
Match[3][1]=DOGS    
Match[4][0]=
<option value="REPTILES">REPTILES</option>
Match[4][1]=REPTILES
Match[5][0]=
<option value="CATS">CATS</option>
Match[5][1]=CATS
Match[6][0]=
<option value="BIRDS">BIRDS</option></select></td>  
    Match[6][1]=BIRDS
```

But i want as mention on top (only values of second dropdown list)

thanks

Comment: What does regex have to do with a dropdown box?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Actually i am doing load testing using jmeter so i need these values to put in further HTTP request in jmeter.

Comment: Consider using an HTML parser here instead of a pure regex.

Comment: is it possible to use pure regex ?

Comment: Check the answer given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Post processor [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) with the following:

```
Reference Name: category (the variable )
CSS/Jquery expression: select[name=account.favouriteCategoryId]> option

Match No. -1 (return all options)
```

You will get the variables:

```
category_1=FISH
category_2=DOGS
category_3=REPTILES
category_4=CATS
category_5=BIRDS
```

You can do it in Regular Expression Extractor using:

```
Regular Expression: favouriteCategoryId">(([\S\s]*)<option value="([^"]+)*">(\w+)<\/option>([ \s\t\n]+)([\S\s]*)+)

Match No: -1 (to get all)
```

Comment: thanks it is working  but i need regular expression becz i have to used regex extractor. is it possible?

Comment: add Regular Expression solution

Answer (score 3):

[It is not recommended to use regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would suggest going for [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

1. Add XPath Extractor as a child of the request which returns the above HTML
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `option`
   - XPath expression: `//select[@name='account.favouriteCategoryId']/option/@value`
   - If response is not XTML/HTML-compliant check `Use Tidy` box

Demo:

[image: XPath Extractor Demo]

References:

- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri its working for me but is it possible to use pure regex?

Comment: Pure regex is not the appropriate tool for this job, because your HTML content is nested.  Instead, use a parser.